# How to listen for defined Activities to come into foreground?

Tags: java, android, rx-java

I want to listen to a list of defined activities to come into foreground.

Basically, I want to do something like this:

- In my main activity define which activities I want to listen to, like so: listenTo(Activity1, Activity2)
- When one of the Activity1 or Activity2 comes into foreground, I want to perform an action.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot listen to which activity has come up inAndroid but I can suggest an alternative to the task you want to do:

Say you want to do task-A when Activity1 and Activity2 come up. Try adding the Task-A in OnStart() of both the activities. OnStart() will be called whenever app is relaunched or launched for first time or comes into foreground when user clicks back of a next activity.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I'm aware  I can do it that way, but I'm trying to explore the possibility of taking the approach I've defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to your application class or call it anywhere with the application context : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same using Rx event bus.
 Let's take example You have three activities A1, A2, A3 and you want to make some API call whenever Activity A1 and A3 comes foreground. We can do same by executing API call in A1 and A3 onStrat() but that's code repetition.

Using Event Bus we can simply throw an Event whenever onStart happens in activity A1 and A3 , and some class will have event listener/subscriber to catch the event and make API call.
link for [RxEventBus](http://blog.kaush.co/2014/12/24/implementing-an-event-bus-with-rxjava-rxbus/)